# Getting Error when try to make https call from express js

Tags: node.js, express, ssl

Getting below error when i try to make https request in express js using axios.

```
let apiUrl = 'https://somedomain.com/products/1/10';
axios.get(apiUrl)
.then(result=>{
    console.log(result);
})
.catch(err=>{
     console.log(err.message);
})
```

Error -

> write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:827:

if anybody got same issue and resolved please help me to get rid of this.

Comment: Try to update to the latest version of axios first. If this still occurs, then [this fix](https://janmolak.com/node-js-axios-behind-corporate-proxies-8b17a6f31f9d) might work

Comment: Have you tried with javascript `fetch` ?

Comment: @robinvrd can we make fetch in expressjs  ??

Comment: @AmruthLS through `node-fect` yes.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Comment: am getting same error with `node-fetch`

Comment: and requesting the url through your browser is working ?

Comment: yeah its working with browser